# how to find file in folder which name starts with a***

Tags: php

right now I am writing code which should do following: 
find a file in a upload folder which one's name starts with, for example, 1234.

I have files with names like :

- 1234photo
- 4581photo24
- 9641photo3

it should only choose the one which starts with 1234.

I am using:

```
glob("upload/*.*")
```

to select all files, how I should change * to select only 1234?
Maybe something like 1234% like it's in sql?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll just need to update the matching pattern to: `"upload/1234*.*"` or `"upload/1234*"`

```
<?php
    foreach (glob("upload/1234*.*") as $filename) {
        echo "$filename size " . filesize($filename) . "\n";
    }
?>
```

The above example will output something similar to:

`upload/1234photo1.jpg size 44686`
`upload/1234photo24.jpg size 267625`

Answer (score 1):

The pattern work the same way as in most OS command lines.
You can just use:

```
$files = glob('upload/1234*');
```